# Full trust in .Net framework 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0

I am working on .Net framework. 
I have created an application that creates a custom culture in my local computer. (Since it is a test application, it'll not be shipped or deployed anywhere else than my computer)

When I try to register the custom culture, it tries to access C:\widows\Globalization folder. I am getting UnauthorizedAccessException.

.Net Framework 4.0 doesn't provide .Net Configuration tool as earlier versions did.

What is the method to know the permissions provided to an assembly?

How to provide full trust to an assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have full trust if you're running from your local drive (which you most likely are). In this case, the problem is that you need to be an *Administrator*. If you're running on Vista or Windows 7, make sure you right-click you .exe and select "Run as Administrator".

Comment: Yes. This works for my need. I am able to run the application as Admin.

Well, is there any way to know the permissions provided to an assembly?